# Count column with specific condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

How can i count columns that hold particular values - but have it as a grand-total.

table data:

```
 Code      No
  1         *
  2         -
  3         4
  4
```

If for example i wanted to count how many rows had * and - and space

I could do

```
Case when No = '*'
Then COUNT(No)
when No = '-' then count(No)
when No = '' then count(No)
else 0 end as 'Count'
```

but this returns 4

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f73409/4

I would want this to return 3

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `IN`:

```
select Sum(Case when No IN ('*', '-', '') then 1 else 0 end) as Count
from Table1
```

See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f73409/2).

Answer (score 0):

Standard SQL has a particular feature for that: the `filter` clause that follows aggregates.

Unfortunately, it is not very widely supported (mainly PostgreSQL).

There is an easy workaround using `case` however:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN 1 END)
```

This works because the implied `else null` clause of `case` and because `count` does not count `null`.

More about the `filter` clause and ways to mimic it: http://modern-sql.com/feature/filter